# kibana keyword occurrency across documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have been unable to show words occurrency in kibana inside a `full_text` field mapped as `"type": "keyword"` across documents in the index.
My first attempt involved the usage of an analyzer. However I have been unable to change the document in any way, the index mapping relfect the analyzer but no field reflect the analysis.
This is the simplified mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "analyzed": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "rebuilt"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt": {
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
  }
}
```

but still I'm unable to see the array of words that I expect to be saved under the `text.analyzed` field, indeed that fields does not exists and I'm wondering why

Answer (score 0):

It seems like settings `fielddata=true` [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html), in spite of being heavily discouraged, solved my problem (at least for now), and allows me to visualize in kibana the occurrence (or absolute frequency) of each word in the `text` field across documents.
The final version of the proposed simplified mapping therefore became:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "rebuilt",
          "fielddata": true
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            } 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt": {
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
  }
}
```

Getting rid of the useless `analyzed` field.
I still have to check the performance of kibana. If someone has a performance safe solution to this problem please do not hesitate.
Thanks.